# Why am I getting 'R cannot be resolved to a variable' on a previously working project(JAVA 8)?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I know that it has been asked thousands of times, but I really can't fix this at this momment. I'm trying to update an old project(already submitet to the play store). The only dependency was the `v7 appcompact` lybrary and so I added it to the new workspace and updated the existing project dep[endencie, but I'm still getting the strange `R cannot be resolved to a variable` error.

Here is what I'm doing and even if I'm 99% sure that it is what I have to do, it's not working.

1. Updating the project dependencie:

[image]

everything looks nice, but when I clean and rebuild the project, here is what happens:

[image]

and the problem is still there. I'm really going to start crying, because it was a working project, buta after switching to a new workspace and checking it out from my git repository, I can't get it working.

Do you have an idea what is going on? I know that I miss something small here, I know that it has been asked so many times, but I can't find an answer fitting on my case.

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal Already tried it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove library project android-support-v7-appcompact and add it again properly.

- also check your package name in manifest file.
- update SDK Build Tools on SDK Tools -> SDK Platform Tools, if not, please try it and clean & rebuild.
- check imports to see any broken R.java imports. if there is "import android.R;" remove it.
- check style and layout xmls to prevent any missing drawables or depreciates.

also see : [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Comment: your screenshot shows it as error. Did you check it again? fixed now?

Comment: I'm adding it properly it seems ok and after the rebuild I'm getting the error shown on the screenshot.

Comment: Remove that support library, and add like this way: 
Right Click on Project -> Android Tools -> Add Support Library...

Did you recenlty update SDK Build Tools on SDK Tools -> SDK Platform Tools, if not, please try it and clean & rebuild

Comment: I tried everything and the R is still giving me errors. I think that I should move to IntelliJ, maybe it will be free of such crazy things...

Comment: Ok I found what is wrong. I see that many things have changed in android the past 2 months...

Answer (score 0):

Just to tell my experience with this problem in a Java project with JDK8. In my case I was running the project in a Mac with Yosemite. Reading the specs. [Android Studio and SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), I've found that projects could be compiled up to Yosemite version.

I changed my environment variables to JDK7 and it worked!